# How do you bind visibility of a component to model state

Tags: java, data-binding, vaadin, vaadin14

Let's say I have a `Grid` containing some `Item`s and a `specialActionButton` that I only want to display when the item selected in the `grid` has type `special`.

Or I want to disable a button until some condition on the model is met.

Currently, I'm thinking of an invisible field bound with a fake `Validator` that does the UI updates.

But that seems like such a bad way to go about this that I'm almost certain there must be a better way.

Comment: Your question has raised some confusion. I suggest you add a simple example with code to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve the behaviour using `ComponentRender`.
Take a look at an example here: [Using Component Renderers](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html#using-component-renderers). 
Instead of `Icon` you can return either a disabled/enabled button.

For example, something like this :

```java
grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(property -> {
        NativeButton button=new NativeButton("Remove");
        if (property.getValue().contains("1")) {
            return button;
        } else {
            button.setEnabled(false);
            return button;
        }
})).setHeader("button");
```

Once you update the item and call `dataProvider.refreshItem(item);` the enabled property will change

Another approach would be to use `setClassNameGenerator` . There is no example, unfortunately, in the documentation, but (apart from the way of importing styles) this thread is very much relevant : [How to set color of cell in Grid in Vaadin 13?](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/17773702/how-to-set-color-of-cell-in-grid-in-vaadin-13)

Answer (score 2):

**Situation 1: Button is outside of the grid**
You can define a `SelectionListener` on the grid, where you can check your criteria for the selected item. Depending on that result, you call `button.setVisible(itemFulfillsCriteria);`

```
// assuming a single select grid
grid.addSelectionListener(selection -> {
    boolean showButton = false;
    MyItem selectedItem = selection.getFirstSelectedItem().orElse(null);
    if(selectedItem != null && selectedItem.getFoo() == Foo.BAR){ // show button only if item.foo == BAR
        showButton = true;
    }
    myButton.setVisible(showButton);
    //myButton.setEnabled(showButton); // if you want to disable instead of hide.
}
```

**Situation 2: Button for each grid row**
When you add the column for this button, you can check inside the Renderer if the item qualifies for having that button visible.

```
grid.addComponentColumn(item -> {
    if(item.getFoo() == Foo.BAR) {
        return new Button("click me", click -> {
            // do something when clicked
        });
    } else {
        return new Span(); // don't return null, as that would cause exception. Instead, return empty Span.
    }
})
    .setKey("someAction")
    .setHeader("Do the thing");
```

**Situation 3: no grid, but a `Binder`**
When you have a binder and want to show/hide or enable/disable a component based on the bound items values, you can define a `ValueChangeListener` on the binder itself. Anytime when the value of a bound inputfield changes, that listener will be triggered and you can then check if the bound item now fulfills your criteria and act accordingly.

```
binder.addValueChangeListener(changeEvent -> {
    MyItem boundItem = binder.getBean();
    button.setVisible(boundItem.getFoo() == Foo.BAR);
    //button.setEnabled(boundItem.getFoo() == Foo.BAR);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But while this will undoubtedly be useful, the question goes beyond that so the rephrasing is wrong: `Or I want to disable a button until some condition on the model is met.` ANY boolean condition, not necessarily tied to a selection.

Comment: @User1291 if you want to disable the button instead of hiding, simply change `button.setVisible(showButton)` to `button.setEnabled(showButton)`. I added this into my answer.

Comment: You're misunderstanding me... I want to disable a button based on a boolean in the model. If the boolean is true, the buttons should be enabled / visible, if the boolean is false, the button should be disabled /hidden and if the boolean changes, the UI should change accordingly. There's no selection, here.

Comment: Is your button just some button on a UI or a button **inside** a grid column? if it's a random button, can you use a grid selection listener to change its enable-property?

Comment: @User1291 your question is really minimal without much explanation. Also it appears now that you are asking two differnet questions? Anyway, From your last comment I assume you are asking for how to do it when you are using a `Binder`. I added a section for this in my answer. For the next time, please take more time when writing the question to make it very clear what you want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

If you want e.g. a button's disabled state to be controlled by a boolean property in your model, it must somehow be notified when the boolean value has changed.

For a generic approach, you might be interested in [View models for Java components](https://vaadin.com/labs/viewmodel). Note that the approach in the article is experimental, and not part of Vaadin's official offering.